# Run64BitRuntime in SSIS package won't stick

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

I developed an SSIS package about 6 months ago to migrate a number of access databases into SQL server.  I opened the package yesterday to go through another run and noticed a few (X) error indicators.  Upon further investigation, the connection managers produced the following error:

> The specified provider is not supported.  Please choose different
>   provider in connection manager.

The connection manager then opens, but the previously selected provider is no longer listed.  Investigating the text in the project file, I was previously using:

- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0

Recalling that I did have to set the Run64BitRuntime to false in order to use the 32 bit providers, I double checked the *Project Properties -> Configuration Propeties -> Debugging -> Run64BitRuntime setting*, which had reverted to `True`. I switched to false, saved, exited and reopened, and the value had again reverted to True.  Several other tries produced the same result.  At this point, I believe that is the issue, but haven't yet found a solution.

For full disclosure, the package was developed on SSDT-BI for VS 2012, and I'm now using SSDT-BI for VS 2013.  I've attempted to create a new package in case there was an issue there, but the same thing happens with a new package.  I also upgraded my Office installation and now have version 16 of the Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) listed in ODBC (32-bit) instead of version 15.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:** An access driver is not listed in the provider list within the Connection Manager, but is listed in ODBC 32-bit providers. The Jet 4.0 provider fails with "Unrecognized database format"

**EDIT 2:** Ran into some posts that indicated if the provider isn't listed VS may be running in 64 bit mode.  I doubled checked to verify it is running in 32 bit mode (as shown in Task Manager).  Maybe my issue is that the provider isn't showing up at all?

**EDIT 3:** Reinstalled SSDT-BI for VS 2012, providers are still missing.

**EDIT 4:** I've tried running the package from VS as well as from the SQL server.  The package was previously able to run in both places.

**EDIT 5:** Decided to try simple ODBC connections instead of the OLE DB provider by adding a new User DSN.  Receiving this error:

> ODBC driver for Microsoft Access installation problem: Unable to load odbcji32.dll

Which lead me to [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-access/unable-to-load-odbcji32dll/de67abd0-f4d8-40af-8e5f-1922b8393d7e?auth=1), which claims the recent Microsoft Office updates are to blame.  Going to try installing the Office 2013 runtime.

Comment: Where do the SSIS jobs run?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in this case, a recent Microsoft Office update was to blame.  Installing the Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime resolved the issue, found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358).  The Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime may also work, found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040), but for me it produced an error stating:

> Windows Installer and Click-to-Run editions of Office programs don't get along for this version...

Comment: Glad you solved it!  I was watching this question, as I had horrible problems with this about a year ago (but couldn't remember what the solution was, the experience was so horrific: so I couldn't post anything helpful).